# Changing CSS with CLICK?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to change the CSS when a link is clicked and return it to its normal state when another link is clicked, changing that CSS, as well?

```
    <div id="nv_wrap">
        <a class="panel nv7" href="#item8"></a>
        <a class="panel nv6" href="#item7"></a>
        <a class="panel nv5" href="#item6"></a>
        <a class="panel nv4" href="#item5"></a>
        <a class="panel nv3" href="#item4"></a>
        <a class="panel nv2" href="#item3"></a>
        <a class="panel nv1" href="#item2"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you able to use JavaScript, to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using jQuery, something like this:

```
$("#nv_wrap a.panel").click(function(){
    $("#nv_wrap a.clicked").removeClass("clicked"); //returns the old one to its normal state
    $(this).addClass("clicked"); //assigns an additional class to the clicked element.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's in fact several ways to do so. In your example you could even use the `a:active` selector, which contains css that only applies to active links.

```
a { color: blue }
a:active { color: red }
```

All links will be blue now, except the one you clicked; that one turns red.

-edit-
tried to show an example in jsfiddle but I guess that doesn't work because of the iframes

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div#nv_wrap a.panel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
});
```

Edit:

example CSS:

```
a { color: blue; }
a.clicked { color: red }
```

Comment: You might also use toggle instead of click.  That way when you click on the same link twice, it resets to not 'clicked'.

Comment: also, since you're using anchor tags, you will need to use preventDefault so the browser doesn't reload.

Comment: Since when the browser reloads on anchors?

Comment: @Alexander, are you using the Socratic method to make a point?

Comment: no, I asked a question. I want to know, in which circumstances this occurs, because in my practice I have never encountered such behavior. If such circumstances exist, I want to know about it. This IS a forum where knowledge is shared among people? I don't care that much about reputation, for today I've reached my daily reputation cap. I am just reading alternative solutions.

Comment: Sorry, "reload" was not the best word for me to use.  The page isn't reloaded, but an anchor tag naturally directs the user to another location when clicked if the href contains a url unless the default event is halted.  Though using href="#" keeps the user on the page so my remarks about it don't apply in this case.

Comment: oh, I see, you got me scared for a while :) I thought I didn't know something that might affect the functionality of my previous work.